# Creating a container with Susy with no margins (Compass/Sass)

Tags: susy-compass

There is an 8px margin on my body element that I don't want to have there because it makes the navigation look a bit strange. I can set the margin-top to be 0 pixels, or set a negative 8 px margin on the navigation, which is better and why does Susy have this in the template anyway?

[image: Navigation has 8px top margin]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not actually related to Susy at all. Susy does not apply any 8px margin to the body, but most browsers do by default. You can use a reset ("`@import "compass/reset";`" would be one way), or simply override the margin setting on the body by hand. I would not use negative margins to fix it, unless you really want 8px margins everywhere else.

Comment: The compass/reset does it for me.